# Enter either a date or a null value in database using MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched the site and although I have found questions and answers similar I haven't been able to find an answer.  After 4 hours of searching I've decided to bite the bullet and ask the question.

I have 4 date fields in a form that aren't required.  I would like it to enter a date into the database if one of the fields has an entry or null if any are left blank.

I have an if statement that checks if the value is empty and if so `$value = null`, otherwise use `$value = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_post['value']))` to convert it to a date and this works well.

The problem is in my query.  If I use '$value' it will insert the date correctly but won't insert a null value because using 'null' makes sql think it's a string.  If I use just $value the null inserts just fine but the date goes in as 0000-00-00.

Any advice would be very much appreciated

Thanks for the advice so far...

Null is allowed, this is my script...

```
if(empty($_POST['fp32_original_install_date'])){
$fp32_install = NULL;
    }else{
$fp32_install = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['fp32_original_install_date']));
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts_cstm (id_c, support_c, install_date_c, sware_renewal_date_c, product_key_c, account_status_c, fp32_support_type_c, fp32_support_renewal_date_c, fp32_original_install_date_c) VALUES ('$Guid','$cdr_support', '$cdr_install', '$cdr_renew', '$prod_key', '$account_status', '$fp32_support', '$fp32_renew', $fp32_install)";
```

If I use in the query $fp32_install a null value goes in just fine but a date goes in as 0000-00-00, if I use '$fp32_install' the date goes in fine but a NULL value goes in as 1970-01-01 (probably because it sees 'NULL' as a string)

If I echo $fp32_install the value is shown as 2012-08-16 and the SQL type for the column is date and the default is NULL

Comment: Wouldn't using PDO with proper placeholders handle the escaping for you?

Comment: It seems your date field on MySQL not allow `NULL`

Comment: Please include your code in the question. It is much easier to answer when we can see a code example.

Comment: Is your MySQL column allowed to be `NULL` or does it have the `NOT NULL` flag?

Comment: Why don't you use the default value. The default value is set when you don't provide anything to the coloumn. You can do that by using MySQL NOW() function. Write this in your query. And if you don't know what I am talking about please submit your complete code with your query.

Comment: if($value=="") $value="NULL"; else $value="'".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value))."'"; // note the quotes around the date but not the NULL

Comment: Waygood, you're da man!  That did the trick perfectly!  How do i acknowledge this for your rep score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using posted values from a form, then $_POST['value'] will not be NULL.

You should check for empty values instead.

```
if($_POST['value']=="")
{
    $value="NULL";
}
else 
{
    $value="'".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['value']))."'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the behavior you describe, it sounds as if your DATE column is defined with a `DEFAULT 0` clause, or you are providing an invalid value.

According to the MySQL documentation:

<snip>

Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').

</snip>

It's difficult to diagnose the exact problem without seeing example code. As a starter, I suggest you try echoing out the SQL statement that is being sent to the database.

I have a strong suspicion that the value for the DATE column is going to appear with quotes around it, a string value of `'NULL'`, rather than the bare keyword `NULL`.